# python virtual environment can't find pip module

Tags: python, pip

I am using python 3.9 in Windows 11.

python can not find pip with virtual environment.
I tried to use ensurepip but it did not solve the problem

below is the console output

1. python without venv

```
PS C:\Users\qnehd\workplace\Python\py-ui> python -m pip --version
pip 23.0.1 from C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
```

2. python with venv

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\qnehd\workplace\Python\py-ui> python -m pip --version  
C:\Users\qnehd\workplace\Python\py-ui\venv\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip  
(venv) PS C:\Users\qnehd\workplace\Python\py-ui> pip --version  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main  
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,  
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code  
    exec(code, run_globals)  
  File "C:\Users\qnehd\workplace\Python\py-ui\venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

3. ensurepip output

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\qnehd\workplace\Python\py-ui> python -m ensurepip -vv
Using pip 23.0.1 from C:\Users\qnehd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpq5tcirqh\pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl\pip (python 3.10)
Non-user install because user site-packages disabled
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.org/simple
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\qnehd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tracker-wlgbodxs
Initialized build tracking at C:\Users\qnehd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tracker-wlgbodxs
Created build tracker: C:\Users\qnehd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tracker-wlgbodxs
Entered build tracker: C:\Users\qnehd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tracker-wlgbodxs
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\qnehd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-03524hs8
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\qnehd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-uttjzu10
Looking in links: c:\Users\qnehd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpq5tcirqh
0 location(s) to search for versions of setuptools:
Found link file:///C:/Users/qnehd/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq5tcirqh/setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl, version: 65.5.0
Skipping link: wrong project name (not setuptools): file:///C:/Users/qnehd/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq5tcirqh/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Local files found: C:\Users\qnehd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpq5tcirqh\setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Given no hashes to check 1 links for project 'setuptools': discarding no candidates
Processing c:\users\qnehd\appdata\local\temp\tmpq5tcirqh\setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Added setuptools from file:///C:/Users/qnehd/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq5tcirqh/setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl to build tracker 'C:\\Users\\qnehd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-tracker-wlgbodxs'
  Removed setuptools from file:///C:/Users/qnehd/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq5tcirqh/setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl from build tracker 'C:\\Users\\qnehd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-tracker-wlgbodxs'
0 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
Skipping link: wrong project name (not pip): file:///C:/Users/qnehd/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq5tcirqh/setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Found link file:///C:/Users/qnehd/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq5tcirqh/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl, version: 23.0.1
Local files found: C:\Users\qnehd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpq5tcirqh\pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Given no hashes to check 1 links for project 'pip': discarding no candidates
Processing c:\users\qnehd\appdata\local\temp\tmpq5tcirqh\pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
  Added pip from file:///C:/Users/qnehd/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq5tcirqh/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl to build tracker 'C:\\Users\\qnehd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-tracker-wlgbodxs'
  Removed pip from file:///C:/Users/qnehd/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq5tcirqh/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl from build tracker 'C:\\Users\\qnehd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-tracker-wlgbodxs'
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\qnehd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-ogku31px
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip


  _find worked: 'pip\\_vendor\\distlib\\t64.exe' 'pip\\_vendor\\'
  _find worked: 'pip\\_vendor\\distlib\\t64.exe' 'pip\\_vendor\\'
Successfully installed pip setuptools
Removed build tracker: 'C:\\Users\\qnehd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-tracker-wlgbodxs'
```

Comment: How did you create this virtual environment?

Comment: I just use "python -m venv ./venv"

Comment: Is this reproducible on your machine? Normally `python -m venv envname` will populate `envname` with `pip` and `setuptools` as well as `python` unless you specifically pass in options to instruct otherwise.